# How to render Css style sheets in MVC bundling

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am getting below error when I run the page ,I am confusing why this error is coming ,below is my screenshot[image]

updated:
below is rendered html
[image]

Comment: How do you include style in page? Please show the code

Comment: I have updated rendered html ,why css error coming not understood I have used Bundle config file to render styles and scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your styles rendered as scripts

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

Try to use separate bundles for scripts

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
            "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
            // "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js", // uncomment if using the Scheduler
            "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));
```

and for styles

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css"));
```